# does $\ln{a}/\ln{b}=\log_ba$ still stand when $a,b\in\Bbb C$? ($b\ne1$)

Tags: logarithms

I've heard that the property of logarithm becomes to have some differences with complex numbers. I'm not sure whether I should apply or not the property that's used with positive numbers.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says it's true for a few different tries, so I'm guessing yes. Also you have to keep in mind that the logarithm is multivalued in the complex plane.

Comment: Note that $a^z=e^{z\log a}$ for complex $a,z$, $a\neq 0$.